# When gaining a new skill through a connection, do players gain it at level 1 or 0?

Tags: character-creation, mongoose-traveller

Gaining one level in any skill seems to fall outside the standard "Skills can be listed with or without an associated level. If no rank is listed, then you gain that skill at Level 1 if you do not have it already, or increases its level by one if you are already trained in that field." due to the lack of listing the actual skill, any clarification on this issue would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You should probably Gain it at Level 1

This case falls between the rules as written so direct rules reference is not really possible. The Connections rule only says:

> For each connection you make, you gain one level in any Skill

The argument against the you get it at Level 1 is that going from untrained to level 0 is also upping the level as this means it you no longer get the penalties for untrained use.

But I would argue that you can see the skill you gain from the connection as a skill listed without an associated level and apply the general rule:

> Skills can be listed with or without an associated level. If no rank is listed, then you gain that skill at Level 1 if you do not have it already, or increases its level by one if you are already trained in that field

The other argument is that the intend of the connection rule is two fold on one side it rewards you for adding a connection and with that a roleplay hook. On the other hand you gain a level in a skill which means you can chose to start with a higher power character balanced with that you increase your Skill Total making [learning new skills](http://www.traveller-srd.com/core-rules/skills/#Learning_new_skills) more work.
Knowing this you can see the intent as raising your Skill Total by one and as untrained skills and Level 0 skills both count as 0 for this total moving a skill from untrained to 0 would not increase the Skill Total

Comment: 0 is not really a level; rather, it's a signal that unskilled penalties do not apply. During character creation, when you roll on the skill table, you "gain a level" in the selected skill; if you don't have the skill before, you get the skill at level 1, not level 0.  The only time you gain a skill at level 0 is when the rules explicitly grant the level 0 skill, e.g., in homeworld/background skills, or career automatic skills on advancement.

Comment: Don't disagree with your characterization, but it is a named skill level. And its effects, in terms of removing the unskilled penalties, is more significant than a single skill level as a modifier, so it's at least as important as a skill level. 

I have always seen level-0 skills as a way to let players have a broader range of unpenalized activities. It's like taking a 2 week to 2 month course in something.... you learn enough to be less incompetent.

Answer (score 1):

No rank is listed, thus you add 1 rank to an existing skill, or gain a new skill at rank 1.  The detail that you choose the skill rather than having a specific skill listed is not significant.

There are very few situations where skills are gained at rank 0 (homeworld background skills, basic training) and, in those cases, you cannot gain or increase the skill above rank 0.  In this case, existing skills can be increased to a maximum of rank 3, thus it is not subject to a "rank 0 and no higher" limitation.

Comment: So if I get a 0 level skill during the homeworld/background step, and then I receive it again without a level attached, it would move to level 1, would it not? 

And what about the case where I have a skill at level 1 and then get an award of that same skill at level 1 (not without a level where it would go to 2) - does it still go to 2? Or is it wasted because I already have level 1 in that skill?

Comment: @user3055321 - If you get an award of a skill at level 1, then you get the skill _at level 1_. If you previously had it at level 0, if becomes level 1.  If you previously had it at level 1 or higher, then it is wasted.  This is the difference between an award of "Pilot" (add 1 to existing skill level) and an award of "Pilot 1" (raise skill level to 1 if lower, do nothing if current skill level is 1 or higher).